# Update value JSON file using php

Tags: php, json

Hello I'm trying to update a JSON file using PHP but it isn't working as I expect, can you try to correct it? I want change "gfdhdfghdfh" to "google.es"
I added the index.php with all code because the script "update.php" is not posting.
update.php:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
$jsonContents = file_get_contents('js/json.json');
$name = $_POST['edit-name'];
$url = $_POST['edit-name1'];
$data = json_decode($jsonContents, true);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['name'] == $name) {
        $data[$key]['url'] == $url;
    }
};
$json = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('js/json.json', $json);

?>
```

It takes the values from 2 boxes of the html code. (Name and Url)

JSON FILE:

```
[{"name":"gfdhdfghdfg","url":"gfdhdfghdfh"}]
```

index.php:

```
<?php
//ADD Links
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    var_dump($_POST);

    $jsonContents = file_get_contents('js/json.json');
    $name = $_POST['addname'];
    $url = $_POST['addlink'];
    $data = json_decode($jsonContents, true);
    $data[] = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'url' => $url
    );
    $json = json_encode($data);
    file_put_contents('js/json.json', $json);
    header('Location: http://URL/index.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>SSL Checker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="security-ssl.png"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var Checker = <?php echo file_get_contents('js/json.json'); ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body onLoad="start()">
    <div id="title">
        <h1>SSL Checker</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="data">
        <form method="POST" onsubmit="SSL.Add()">
            <input type="text" name="addname" id="add-name" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="text" name="addlink" id="add-link" placeholder="Link" />
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </form>
        <div id="edit" role="aria-hidden">
            <form action="update.php" method="POST" id="saveEdit">
                <input type="text" id="edit-name">
                <input type="text" id="edit-name1">
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" /> <a onclick="CloseInput()" aria-label="Close">&#10006;</a>
            </form>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="dl">
        <p id="counter"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="table">

       <table style="overflow-x:auto;">
       <tr>
           <th>Sites:</th>
       </tr>
           <tbody id="urls">
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: input, and expected and actual output please?

Comment: What values does it currently have? What values should it have?

Comment: I added the values of JSON file

Comment: And I explained better the problem

Comment: are you entering "gfdhdfghdfg" in edit-name and "google.es" in edit-name1?

Comment: Assuming the post values are set correctly, the logic works fine once you've fixed the double-equals issue. See https://eval.in/1009254

Comment: Yes, and it didn't change nothing

Comment: @iainn What can I do for comprove if the post values are set correctly? because it don't work

Comment: var_dump($_POST); results = array(0) { }

Comment: Your inputs in the second form don't have names

Comment: Thanks you @iainn it was the problemm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a double equals in your if statement. Change it to one equals to assign a value.

```
$data[$key]['url'] == $url;
```

to

```
$data[$key]['url'] = $url;
```

UPDATE

Based on following pastes and comments, it's the form POST which isn't sending, because the form elements only have an id and not a name.

Comment: Thanks you but it didn't solve the problem to update the file :/

Comment: Okay I now see your JSON. But can you `var_dump($_POST)` please?

Comment: paste the content of var_dump($_POST) along with the question.

Comment: How can I see the content of var_dump?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST); exit;`

Comment: Okey, it is the result: array(0) { }

Comment: Ok, so your form never posted, therefore $value['name'] will never `==` gfdhdfghdfg

Comment: How can I solve it? I can send my html code if you want too

Comment: I posted my "main page" index.php

Comment: what is this?  `onsubmit="SSL.Add()"`

Comment: Its for add links to the json file, but it works, now I'm doing the section to "edit" the json file

Comment: it's stopping the $_POST

Comment: How can I compatibility the 2 process?

Comment: I found the misstake there weren't "name" set on the imput name-edit, can you add it on your answer and I'll accept the answer as corret?